# Can't get Lookup column data from list in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-rest-api, error, lookup-column

My list name is 'EmployeeData' and in that list my lookup column name is 'SectorId' and that column actual name is 'Sector'.

I want title of that lookup column:

```
https://site name /_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('EmployeeData')/items?select=SecotrId/Title&$expand=SectorId&$Filter=UserId%20eq%20%276%27
```

but I can't get the data.

I also tried:
`Sector/Title$&expand=Sector` but it's showing same error "the sectorId" query field is not valid.

Comment: I think there is a typo as you mention your field name is `SectorId` and in query you are using `SecotrId/Title`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the internal name of your column in SharePoint REST API endpoint.

Check this article to find the correct internal name of your column: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/).

Assuming internal name is `Sector`, you have to use endpoint like:

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('EmployeeData')/items?select=Title,Sector/Title&$expand=Sector&$Filter=UserId eq '6'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following api to get lookuo column

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('List2')/items?$select=Title,lookup/Title&$expand=lookup
```